# How to hide a shape during the slideshow?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to hide a rectangle shape during the slide show and in the output video. I have tried with 'appear' animation on the shape to be hidden with "start animation on click", and setting "advance slide to 5 seconds", thinking that, if I don't click, the 'appear animation' won't run & the shape would be invisible during the slideshow. But the appear animation RUNS even without any click before going to the next slide.

In short, I want to hide a shape, while running the slide show. Any idea is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You try the "Disappear" exit animation in the Exit group.

Comment: @harrymc No luck. Already tried the "Disappear" exit animation with 0.01 seconds duration, it is not smooth. since it disappears after the Transition of the current slide finishes. It is unsuccessful even without any Transition on the current slide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use the Selection pane and click the eye icon next to
the listed shape to make it invisible.
Click again to make it visible whenever you wish to see it,
but keep it hidden otherwise.

The other method I can think of is more clumsy, which is to keep two copies
of the slide, one with and the other without the shape, and keep the
slide with the shape as hidden from the slideshow.

Comment: Thank you. It is really a decent workaround. If there is no other useful answer, it should be accepted.