# How can I edit a textbox hidden behind an image in Microsoft PowerPoint, without changing the resulting presentation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a slide containing a textbox hidden behind an image in Microsoft PowerPoint. How can I edit the text without changing the resulting presentation?

If I use the “Send Backward/Forward” feature, it'll change the resulting presentation.

---

E.g., blue rectangle hiding a textbox:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide a shape during the slideshow?](https://superuser.com/questions/1706363/how-to-hide-a-shape-during-the-slideshow)

Comment: @harrymc thanks, not a dupe, here I ask "How can I edit a textbox hidden behind an image in Microsoft PowerPoint, without changing the resulting presentation?". Hiding is 1 method, there could be other ways.

Comment: Yet your answer is exactly the same method as in that post...

Comment: @harrymc agreed, it's not a good situation. I wish one could post a pointer to an answer as an answer. FYI: [Are there any non-trivial examples of exact-duplicate answers to non-duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267318/178179). I'm just afraid that by closing this question we could miss other solutions.

Comment: @harrymc I added a 2nd solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Answer](https://redd.it/wqge7o) from Reddit user [taiphuun](https://www.reddit.com/user/taiphuun) and [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1706503/116475) by [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc): one can hide it from the [selection pane](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-objects-with-the-selection-pane-a6b2fd3e-d769-46c1-9b9c-b94e04a72550): <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, or `Home -> select -> selection pane`.

Demo:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](https://redd.it/wqge7o) from Reddit user [SteveRindsberg](https://www.reddit.com/user/SteveRindsberg):

> You'll need to send it to front, edit it, then send it back behind whatever was hiding it.
>
> If it's something you find yourself doing often, I have a free addin, PPTools THOR, that you could use. Use tab or selection pane to select the text, use THOR to memorize its position, drag the text to someplace where you can see it (or use arrow keys) and edit it. Then click THOR's hammer to put it back where it came from, still in original Z-order.
>
> You can find THOR here: https://pptools.com/free/